# java.lang.SecurityException Neither user 10145 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android

My app has added this permission , but in some device has this error message, all in android 4.4(4.4.2)

> java.lang.SecurityException Neither user 10145 nor current process has
>   android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.

Comment: What is your targetsdk?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 23

Answer (score 12):

If You Are Using Acra Library Check This Answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972790/7377631

> Your app is probably using a new version of ACRA library. In new the version they added  to the lib AndroidManifest.xml file. The android:maxSdkVersion="25" is silently merged to main app AndroidManifest.xml file, hence the app doesn't have WAKE_LOCK permission on Oreo devices. The solution is add tools:node="replace" to your uses-permission declaration.

For example `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" tools:node="replace"/>`.

Comment: I'm not using Acra, but this solved my problem with workmanager.

Comment: This worked for issues in my project with SFMC integration. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Android permissions are case sensitive. So check whether you have added the permission correctly.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Also there is a known bug in Marshmallow. So try building by changing your targetsdk version is it is Android 6.0.

Comment: i don't think so ,i have added the permission correctly , and it just happened on some device(4.4),not all