# Cannot get WAKE_LOCK permission on Android 8 Oreo

Tags: android, permissions

My app has `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` added to the `AndroidManifest.xml`. However calls to acquire the lock `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` crash the app on Oreo devices.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10094 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
```

Comment: Care to post any errors and exceptions you're getiing?

Comment: Android O had huge  [behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes) regarding wakelocks, broadcasts and background services.

Comment: @Pawel , WAKE_LOCK is a normal permission, so it's abnormal to have a problem with it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your app is probably using a new version of ACRA library. In new the version they added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:maxSdkVersion="25" />` to the lib `AndroidManifest.xml` file. The `android:maxSdkVersion="25"` is silently merged to main app `AndroidManifest.xml` file, hence the app doesn't have `WAKE_LOCK` permission on Oreo devices. The solution is add `tools:node="replace"` to your uses-permission declaration.

For example `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" tools:node="replace" />`.

Update: in recent versions of ACRA library that unfortunate "feature" has been [removed](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/commit/fb1996337808d433bc849498dce0ba69ac7e9680).

Comment: I Have Wasted Two Days On This, If it's the Correct Answer You Are A God!

Comment: Yes It's The Correct Answer, Now You Are Officially A God. :D

Comment: My issue also has been resolved with this answer, thanks Greg Dan.