# My app crashes when connection change broadcast intent is received

Tags: android, mqtt, android-wake-lock, aws-appsync

I am using AWS AppSync service, which use [Mqtt Service library](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android),

On Android 8 (Google Pixel), when I start the app, it crashes:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent 
{ act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } 
in org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService$NetworkConnectionIntentReceiver@fdb4f10
...
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10548 
nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK.
```

Which is quite weird, cause I have that permission in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Did anybody experience the same issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972669/cannot-get-wake-lock-permission-on-android-8-oreo - this might be a similar thing? Both are Android 8.

Comment: Did you register <receiver in manifest?

Comment: That's right @sbso. Unbelievable!